# How to parse each line of a text file as an argument to command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, powershell

I'm looking to write a script for Windows Command Prompt that takes a .txt (filename) as an argument, reads the file line by line, and passes each line to a command. If my `FILE.txt` looks like:

```
LINE1
LINE2
LINE3
.
.
.
```

It runs:

`command_name argument --option LINE1`, then

`command_name argument --option LINE2`, after successful execution of first command. And *keep running the same command with different arguments* picked line by line from `FILE.txt`.

The **Linux/UNIX version of what I want to achieve looks like this:**

`cat FILE.txt | xargs -L 1 echo --option | xargs -L 50 command_name argument`

Comment: `cat FILE.txt | % { start -f command_name -a "argument","--option $_" }`

Comment: Why the `bash` tag?

Comment: Did you mean `BATCH` for Windows that you are looking for doing the same thing ?

Answer (score 3):

With ***Powershell*** :

```
foreach($line in GC PathFolder\File.txt) {Write-Host command_name argument --option $Line}
```

---

With ***Command line*** : Using `FOR /f`

```
For /f "delims=" %a in ('Type "File.txt"') do (echo command_name argument --option %a)
```

---

With a ***Batch File*** :

```
@echo off
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "File.txt"') do ( echo command_name argument --option %%a)
pause
```

---

Or
Refer to [Read a file line by line and save it in variable batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926276/3080770)

You can do something like this :

```dos
@echo off
Color 0B & Title Read and parse each line of a text file as an argument to command prompt
set "File2Read=file.txt"
If Not Exist "%File2Read%" (Goto :Error)
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
REM Display array elements
@For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo "Var%%i" is assigned to ==^> "!Line[%%i]!"
    echo command_name argument --option !Line[%%i]!
)
pause>nul
Exit
::-------------------------------------------
:Error
cls & Color 4C
echo(
echo   The file "%File2Read%" dos not exist !
Pause>nul
exit /b
::-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: should be accepted.